# Is there and neat equivalent to view a member function/variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-range, range-v3

[Streams library](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/07/cpp14-streams-lazy-functional) has a neat `map` function to view a range by a member function. Is there any equivalent view in [Range-V3](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/07/cpp14-streams-lazy-functional)?

Would `view::transform` be the only option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example from the article:

```
std::vector widgets = /* ... */    
std::set ids = stream::MakeStream::from(widgets)
         .map(&Widget::getId)
         .to_set();
```

(ignoring the missing template arguments for `std::vector` and `std::set`) in ranges-v3 would be:

```
std::vector<Widget> widgets = // ...
std::set<Widget::ID> ids = widgets | ranges::view::transform(&Widget::getId);
```

Yes, `transform` is the equivalent to `map` in Streams.

All the algorithms in range-v3 accept [Invokable Projections](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections) that allow enable the algorithm to select range elements on the basis of a transformation, but still operate on the entire element. For example, we can sort the `Widget`s by their IDs:

```
widgets |= ranges::action::sort(std::greater<Widget::ID>{}, &Widget::getId);
```

Comment: Thank you. Conceptually speaking I think that there should be some sort of difference between transform and select. A transformation seems like something that processes the data of some way. (ie ...view::transform([](arg0) { return arg0*arg0; }) ) or similar.

Comment: There is no logical distinction between "select" and "transform". Why have two views when one will do? Also, no need to use an action, Casey. The algorithm works fine: `ranges::sort(widgets, std::greater<Widget::ID>{}, &Widget::getId);`

Comment: @EricNiebler Thinking about it, youre absolutely correct, I take it back 100%

Comment: Thinking about it; something like `#define SELECT(pMember) ranges::view::transform([](const auto& val) { return val.pMember; })` yielding `auto ids = widgets | SELECT(getId());` would still be pretty sweet.

Comment: I dont think it could be achieved without a macro thou.